# Django error 'model' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I am following a Django tutorial to lean and I came up with an TypeError at /x/ I am not sure what I am doing wrong

here is the model

```
class articulos(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    seccion = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    precio =  models.IntegerField()
```

here are the views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from GestionPedido.models import articulos

def buscar(request):

    if request.GET["prd"]:
        #mensaje = "Artículo buscado: %r" %request.GET["prd"]
        producto = request.GET["prd"]

        articulo = articulos.objects.filter(nombre__icontains = producto)

        return render(request, "resultadobusqueda.html", {"articulos":articulos, "query":producto})

    else: 
        mensaje = "No has introducido nada %r"

    return HttpResponse(mensaje)
```

and here is the temple

```
<html>

<body>

    <p>Estas buscando: <strong>{{query}}</strong></p>

    {% if articulos %}

        <p>Articulos encomtrados {{articulos|length}} articulos</p>

        <ul>

            {% for articulo in articulos %}
                <li>
                    {{articulos.nombre}}
                </li>

            {% endfor %}

        </ul>>

     {% else %} 

        <p>Articulos no encontrado</p>

    {% endif %}




</body>

</html>
```

it does mark the error `{% for articulo in articulos %}`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in

```
{"articulos":articulos, ...
```

the variable name is `articulo` without 's'. You are passing the model instead of the queryset

Comment: Thank you very much, I couldn't see it, now that I have someone else pointing up the error I understand. I am still learning so you might see me a lot around asking questions. thank you for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

```
articulo = articulos.objects.filter(nombre__icontains = producto)

return render(request, "resultadobusqueda.html", {"articulos":articulos, "query":producto})
```

You are passing "articulos", de model, not "articulo", de queryset.